# Netty worker threads

Tags: event-handling, netty, nio, worker

In my netty server, I create threadpools as follows.

```
    ChannelFactory factory =
        new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory),
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory);
```

Sometimes, I noticed that after a certain number of connections are being worked on by the server, the subsequent connections wait for one of the priors threads to finish.

From the documentation of newCachedThreadPool, I was under the assumption that the thread pool creates new threads as needed. Could someone help me understand why some of my connections being blocked till the prior connections finish? Would netty not create a new thread for new connection, as all the existing ones are busy?

How do I fix this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.

At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks.

If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.

The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.

[from Oracle Java Doc  for newCachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29)!

so the thread number is fixed by Executors.newCachedThreadPool

in netty  default number is processer_number *2

:)

Comment: When using newCachedThreadPool the threadpool does not have fixed pool size. From the link you have given, newCachedThreadPool "Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available.".

Comment: "The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown." This is true for newFixedThreadPool. But for newCachedThreadPool, "Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache."

Comment: i found " If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool"   If you have a new connection and no thread  netty will create a new thread for the connection ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip on max number of workers being 2 * number of processors in NioServerSocketChannelFactory. This was the reason for new request waiting for a running thread.